# To Get Specified number to rows in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gridview

I have an imported excelsheet in GridView. Now i've to send an email to all records but in a way like email is to be sent after selecting top 10 records from Grid View and when the process is complete an email is send again to the next 10 records and so on.

Following is my code:

```
void Send_Mail()
    {
        try
        {
            string Pass, FromEmailid, HostAdd;

            foreach (GridViewRow gr in DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                HostAdd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"].ToString();
                FromEmailid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMail"].ToString();
                Pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();

                Label LblName = gr.FindControl("LblName") as Label;
                Label LblMail = gr.FindControl("LblEmail") as Label;

                string Name = LblName.Text;
                string Mail = LblMail.Text;
                string subject = TxtSubject.Text;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmailid, Pass);

                client.Host = HostAdd;
                client.Port = 25;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(FromEmailid);
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = ReadTemplate(Name);
                msg.To.Add(Mail);
                msg.From = from;

                client.Send(msg);
                LblMessage.Text = "Email Send Successfully";
                LblMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you haven't mentioned what you actually need. Whether you need to send different mails or something.... 
You can try something like this

```
void Send_Mail()
    {
        try
        {
             int rowCount = 0; 
            string Pass, FromEmailid, HostAdd;

            foreach (GridViewRow gr in DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                rowCount++;
                if(rowCount == 10)
                  {
                     SendMail1();
                  }
                else if (rowCount == 20)
                  {
                      SendMail2();
                   }

            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This is not an exact answer.So try to do something by applying this..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have to send the email from 10 by 10.. Mail will send to 10 records at first and then resend to the next 10 records. Actually there are 3000 records that's why i do want to send email to all records directly. So i want to send the mail 100 by 100.. Ok?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that. Finally the output is same no?
Is there something to do when you send first 100 mails???